Project structure in React and Node
I'm creating an online store using React and Node. You need to create an admin panel. Do I need to create a new project for it, or can I do everything in one? Is it necessary to create a new Node js project to develop the logic for working with the admin panel?
I understand that you can do everything in one project by setting up routing and specifying the necessary backend for the panel, but is this solution correct?

Yes, that's right, if your project is not too big, you can do it in one back-end and one front-end. This won't be a problem if you do the middleware and routes correctly.
